# UICollectionViewCell with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have the following nib setup in Interface Builder that contains my viewController's main view (with UICollectionView) and reusable views for header and cells

[image]

I register for reusable views in viewDidLoad

```
[self.calendarView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"dayCell"];
[self.calendarView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"dayCellDisabled"];
[self.calendarView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"monthHeader"];
```

When I try to access my cell label like this:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"dayCellDisabled" forIndexPath:indexPath];    
UILabel *dayLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

the resulting `dayLabel` is nil, therefore I cannot assign it a value, and my view displays nothing. The same applies to my reusable header view and its Year and Month labels.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Several things:

- Registering a nib for cell reuse requires that the cell be the top-level object in that nib - you can't have a multi-content nib like this. Either pull the cell out into a separate nib or use a storyboard and prototypes
- Registering a *class* for cell reuse implies that you will be building the cell's contents in code, which I guess you're not doing given the above. A registered class has no knowledge of that nib file.
- Tags are almost always the wrong thing to do - create a subclass and use outlets instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I created separate classes for cells and header view and now it works